# Ships movement on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openstreetmap, leaflet

I am doing an interactive map with the aim of simulating a real harbour.
I used leaflet.js and openstreetmap.org to create my map, and now I have to add layers for buoys, ships and so on.

To add static object as buoys I used simple markers with customized icons, and that's works fine.
But what about the moving ships? I must represent them in continuos moving on the map, and I must show their dimension, their orientation time by time.

I have five points coordinates to draw them as polygons on the map but I'm not really sure in its better to use a rotated L.icon leaflet object

```
Layer = L.geoJson(null, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {

        return new L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'img/ship.png',
                    iconRetinaUrl: 'img/ship@2x.png',
                    iconSize: [18, 24]
                }) 
        }).on('click', function() {
            $scope.openPanel('ships', feature);
        });
    }
});
```

or to draw a leaflet Polygon

```
var p1 = new L.LatLng(51.509, -0.08),
    p2 = new L.LatLng(51.503, -0.06),
    p3 = new L.LatLng(51.51, -0.047),
    p4 = new L.LatLng(51.503, +0.06),
    p5 = new L.LatLng(51.51, +0.047),
    polygonPoints = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5];

var ship = new L.Polygon(polygonPoints);
     map.addLayer(ship);
```

Considering the dynamic movements of the ships, what is the best solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check out this cool plug in for leaflet.
https://github.com/openplans/Leaflet.AnimatedMarker might help with getting your icons to move about on a line. As for the orientation you may need to have several similar icons (at varying orientations like facing away, facing forward, etc.) and change the icon depending on the direction it is traveling, or which point on the line is next? Hope this helps. Good luck! 
P.S. if you get it working I would love to see it in action

Comment: Hi Chris, I already knew that plugin, but i really prefer to find a solution with polygons since I have all points of ship geometry.

Answer (score 0):

After drawing your polygon and adding it to the map under the variable `ship`, you can call [setLatLngs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline-setlatlngs) to change the positions of its corners.